# missing CSS classes when using beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get data with beautiful soup, but when I try to select a class I see during the inspect process it comes out empty.

```
url = requests.get("https://www.livescore.com/en/football/2022-12-06/")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(url.text,'lxml')
soup.select('.Dk')
```

Comment: what you want to extract from that website?

Comment: I want to extract the result of the ongoing world cup games

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The data you see is loaded from external URL in the form of Json. To display it you can use next example:

```py
import json
import requests


url = "https://prod-public-api.livescore.com/v1/api/app/date/soccer/20221206/1"
data = requests.get(url).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for s in data["Stages"]:
    print(s["Snm"])
    print("-" * 80)
    for e in s["Events"]:
        print(
            "{:<30} {:<30} {:^3}-{:^3}".format(
                e["T1"][0]["Nm"],
                e["T2"][0]["Nm"],
                e.get("Tr1", ""),
                e.get("Tr2", ""),
            )
        )
    print()
```

Prints:

```
Round of 16
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Morocco                        Spain                           0 - 0 
Portugal                       Switzerland                     6 - 1 

National League
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Boreham Wood                   Oldham Athletic                 2 - 1 
FC Halifax Town                Dorking Wanderers               3 - 1 

LaLiga Smartbank
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Leganes                        Mirandes                        2 - 2 
Real Oviedo                    Las Palmas                      0 - 0 
Albacete                       Real Zaragoza                   0 - 0 

Premier League
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Al Masry                       National Bank                   0 - 0 

Club Friendlies
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Athletic Bilbao                Real Valladolid                 2 - 0 
Genk                           SC Heerenveen                   3 - 1 
Panetolikos                    Anderlecht                      1 - 2 
SV Ried                        First Vienna FC                 6 - 1 
Atromitos                      Nottingham Forest               3 - 2 
Galatasaray                    Villarreal                      3 - 4 
Cambridge United               West Ham United                 2 - 4 

1st League
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FC Syunik                      Ararat Yerevan II               1 - 3 

1st Division
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FK Qarabag-2                   Zira FK 2                       0 - 1 
Imisli FK                      FK Sumgayit-2                   3 - 2 
Shamakhi FK-2                  FK Kapaz 2                      1 - 0 

Ligue 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Etoile Du Congo                AS Bng                            -   
FC Nathalys de Pointe-Noire    Inter Club Brazzaville            -   
AS Otoho                       Leopards de Dolisie               -   
AS Cheminots                   V. Club Mokanda                   -   
AS Juk                         Cara Brazzaville                  -   

2nd Division: Group C
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Baladiyyat Al-Mehalla          Proxy                           3 - 2 

National League: North
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Blyth Spartans                 Southport                         -   
Curzon                         Darlington                      0 - 2 
Farsley Celtic AFC             King's Lynn Town                2 - 0 
Hereford                       Chorley                         1 - 1 
Kettering Town                 Gloucester City                 0 - 1 
Leamington                     Brackley Town                   0 - 0 
Scarborough Athletic           Peterborough Sports             2 - 1 
Spennymoor Town                Boston United                   3 - 2 

National League: South
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Braintree Town                 Oxford City                     0 - 0 
Cheshunt                       Dover                           2 - 0 
Dulwich Hamlet                 Chelmsford                      2 - 1 
Hampton & Richmond             Taunton Town                      -   
Hemel Hempstead                Bath City                       1 - 0 
Slough Town                    Concord Rangers                 0 - 0 
Tonbridge Angels               Eastbourne Borough              3 - 0 
Welling United                 Farnborough                     1 - 2 
Worthing                       Ebbsfleet United                0 - 6 

Northern Premier League
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Marske United                  Liversedge                        -   
Whitby                         Hyde United                     1 - 1 

Southern League Premier: Central
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AFC Rushden & Diamonds         Tamworth                        1 - 3 
Alvechurch                     Stratford Town                  4 - 2 
Basford United                 Kings Langley                   0 - 1 
Coalville Town                 Nuneaton Town                   0 - 2 
Needham Market                 Hednesford                      1 - 0 
Rushall Olympic                Leiston                         0 - 2 

Southern League Premier: South
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bracknell Town                 Plymouth Parkway                0 - 0 
Yate Town                      Chesham United                  0 - 3 

Isthmian League Premier Division
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Corinthian Casuals             Bishop's Stortford              0 - 1 
Hastings                       Canvey Island                   1 - 1 
Herne Bay                      Billericay                      2 - 2 
Hornchurch                     Folkestone Invicta              2 - 1 

Premier League U18
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Nottingham Forest U18          Manchester City U18             2 - 2 

Premier League
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Adama City FC                  Legetafo Legedadi               3 - 0 
Bahir Dar Kenema FC            Saint George SC                 0 - 0 

Erovnuli Liga 2: Qualification
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FC Kolkheti Khobi              FC Rustavi                      1 - 0 
WIT Georgia Tbilisi            Aragvi Dusheti                  0 - 0 

I-League
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Real Kashmir                   Sreenidi Deccan                 2 - 1 
Churchill Brothers             Mohammedan SC                   2 - 1 

Liga 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Persebaya Surabaya             Barito Putera                   3 - 2 
Persija Jakarta                Borneo FC Samarinda             1 - 0 
Persis Solo                    RANS Nusantara                  6 - 1 

Premier League
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Arnett Gardens                 Molynes United                  2 - 1 

Premier League: Group B
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Asswehly SC                    Al Ahli Tripoli                 2 - 0 

League Cup
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Cliftonville                   Coleraine                       2 - 2 
Glentoran                      Linfield                        0 - 3 

League Cup: Group H
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Estoril                        Torreense                       2 - 2 

U23 Championship: Group A
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Gil Vicente U23                Sp. Braga U23                   2 - 0 
Vizela U23                     FC Famalicao U23                2 - 2 

U23 Championship: Group B
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Portimonense U23               Sporting Cp U23                 3 - 2 
SC Farense U23                 Estoril Praia U23               4 - 1 
Mafra U23                      Sl Benfica U23                  0 - 1 

Romanian Cup: Group A
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FC Unirea 2004 Slobozia        Dinamo Bucuresti                3 - 3 
Petrolul Ploiesti              U Craiova 1948                  0 - 1 
Sepsi OSK                      FC Voluntari                    4 - 0 

Lowland League
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Celtic B                       Berwick Rangers                 1 - 3 
Rangers B                      East Kilbride                   0 - 0 
Tranent Juniors                Cumbernauld Colts               2 - 1 

Reserve League
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Dundee FC Reserves             Hamilton Academical Reserves    1 - 1 
Kilmarnock Reserves            Livingstone Reserves              -   
Motherwell Reserves            Dundee United FC                  -   
Queen of the South Reserves    Hibernian FC Reserves             -   
Ayr United Reserves            Queens Park Reserve               -   

Prva Liga
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Gorica                         NK Bravo                        0 - 0 
Maribor                        Radomlje                        7 - 0 

Primera Division RFEF: Group 1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Fuenlabrada                    Merida                          0 - 1 
Rayo Majadahonda               Real Madrid Castilla            1 - 2 
Unionistas de Salamanca        Alcorcon                        2 - 1 
CD Badajoz                     Deportivo La Coruna             1 - 0 

Primera Division RFEF: Group 2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Logrones                       Real Sociedad B                 1 - 1 
La Nucia                       CF Intercity                    0 - 0 

Ligue 2: Group A
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Avenir de La Marsa             AS Mehamedia                    4 - 1 
Club Olympique de Medenine     ES Djerba Midoun                1 - 1 
ES Rades                       JS Kairouanaise                 1 - 0 
ES Ragba                       AS Gabes                        1 - 0 
Jendouba Sport                 AS Oued Ellil                   1 - 2 
Sportif de Korba               CS Bembla                       0 - 0 

Premier League
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Arua Hill SC                   BUL FC                          0 - 1 
UPDF FC                        URA FC                          1 - 1 

President's Cup
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Al-Taawoun                     Al-Hamriyah                     1 - 2 
Fursan Hispania                Gulf FC                         0 - 2 
Al-Dhafra                      Baynounah SC                    3 - 0 

Cymru North
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Guilsfield FC                  Porthmadog                      4 - 0 

Cymru South
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Afan Lido                      Ynyshir Albions FC              1 - 0 
Ammanford                      Pontardawe Town                 3 - 2 
Barry Town                     Cwmbran Celtic                  2 - 1 
Briton Ferry                   Abergavenny Town FC             8 - 0 
Cambrian & Clydach             Swansea University              2 - 3 
Carmarthen                     Taffs Well                      1 - 1 
Goytre United                  Llantwit Major                  4 - 3 
Llanelli                       Trefelin BGC                    1 - 4
```